# Where to find already filled in databases

Tags: database, modeling, data-migration

I am new to using external databases, and i was wonderding if there might be a place with many "common"databases?

I know db can be very product specific but i'm talking about like:

- Car brand + model
- Food + nutrisious values
- ...

(Common stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Database structure varies with requirements so you may not find what you need exactly but however, if you just need sample databases, then try Google search. 
Make sure you don't use any of those for a real time projects.

Comment: Unless i would be copying the data to my own DB server. Besides the fact that the found data might be incorrect i dont see anything else what could be harmfull ?